# reverse proxy with nginx that does "not block" on slow internet connection

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy

I have website with following set up

- cloudflare
- nginx as reverse proxy
- Apache mod_php as backend

When a visitor hit php webpage, the webpage is stream from Apache to nginx to cloudflare to visitor's browser.

All this usually happens in parallel. E.g. when the page header have reached visitor's browser, the page footer is still in Apache mod_php.

From time to time I face following problem - suppose Cloudflare or datacenter slows down. In this case, even Apache server is fast enough the webpage "stay" in Apache, because nginx can not read it, because nginx "output" is blocked.

In that case, Apache is fill with running PHP's, they fill MySQL with running queries (queries are executed, but data stay in MySQL, because Apache server is waiting for nginx)

Solution to all this could be if nginx can stream all the content from the Apache into temporary file (or even better in memory) in case "output" is blocked.

Is there such setting in nginx? or there is some set up that might avoid such problem?

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you mean and what you are trying to achieve in the end

Comment: is very hard to explain. if cloudflare is slow, our database server LA spikes to 100+